# how to fix "truncate string" that is not returning string value of length by add 2

Tags: javascript

I am trying to to return truncate string. It’s returned few tasks but error string length.

I have tried few if statement and for loop but its not working for me.

```
function truncateString(str, num) {
  // Clear out that junk in your trunk
  let result = "";
  for (let i=0; i<num; i++) {
    result += str[i];
  }
  if (num < str.length) {
    result = result + "...";
  } 
 return result;
}

truncateString("A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket", 8);
//that work find.
truncateString("A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket", "A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket".length + 2); 
//error
```

output is A-tisket for.

Comment: Of course it will give error. Check the values of `str.length` & `num`. Then you will understand why you are getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

For a fix to your current approach, you may simply return the input string immediately should the requested ellipsis length be equal or greater than the length of the input:

```js
function truncateString(str, num) {
    if (str.length <= num) return str;
    let result = "";

    for (let i=0; i < num; i++) {
        result += str[i];
    }
    if (num < str.length) {
        result = result + "...";
    } 
    return result;
}

var output = truncateString("A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket", "A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket".length + 2);
console.log(output);
```

I prefer a regex based solution here:

```js
var input = "A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket";
var output = input.replace(/^(.{1,8})(.*)$/, "$1...");
console.log(output);
```

This solution matches and captures up to the first 8 characters in the string.  Then, it replaces with only those first characters followed by an ellipsis (`...`).

Comment: Thank's for your answer but in the project we not allowed to use regex, we have to solve with for loop. thanks

Comment: @Iffy I edited my answer to include a fix to your exact current code.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution

```
function truncateString(str, num) {
  // Clear out that junk in your trunk
  let result = "";
  for (let i=0; i<num; i++) {
    result += str[i];
  }
  if (num < str.length) {
    result = result + "...";
  }
  else if (str.length <= num) {
    return str;;
  } 

return result;
}

truncateString("A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket", 8);
//Output A-tisket...
truncateString("A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket", "A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket".length + 2);
//Output A-tisket a-tasket A green and yellow basket
``
```